# How to keep my non-breaking spaces with HTML Tidy (PHP)?

Tags: php, html, htmltidy

I've just noticed that `tidy_repair_string()` is removing my non-breaking spaces from empty elements causing my table to collapse.  Basically I've put in:

> `<td>&nbsp;</td>`

and HTML Tidy is stripping them out to:

```
<td> </td>
```

which may or may not be some Unicode break but either way it's collapsing.  The only `&nbsp;` related option I've seen is 'quote-nbsp' but that doesn't seem to be it.  I think it defaults to on anyway.

How do I keep my non-breaking spaces?

Comment: Does it replace the   for the representing character or just for a normal space?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apply this style, then you do not need to put content in the "empty" cells:

td { [empty-cells](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_tab_empty-cells.asp): show; }

Comment: If i remember correctly, you're supposed to put that on the table, not the cell.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#empty-cells
Applies to table-cell elements.  You typically see it applied to a row or table and inheritance takes care of the rest, but it can be applied to single cells (or, more commonly, to styles applied to single cells).

Comment: Learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 2):

use the "bare" config option.

more information and an explanation available here: http://osdir.com/ml/web.html-tidy.user/2004-07/msg00005.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

`$myString = str_replace("  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;", $someText);`